# Unable to invoke Bing Translator service on WP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services, windows-phone-8

After the migration, gone are the good old days when Microsoft provides a handful of functions on Bing Translation. And new account keys are only valid to the new service root:

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1
```

instead of something like:

```
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc
```

or:

```
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc
```

And that's not the end. When I try to add service reference to it, the VS just says:

```
EntityType 'Microsoft.Translation' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

Or throws some exception on permission.

Before that, I tried to use the Helper Class that ships with the subscription. It took me long to modify the code for use on WP8 - regarding some issues on System.Data.Services.Client (some incompatibility caused by WCF 5 on the client?) and asynchronous calls. The result was:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:There is a type mismatch between the client and the service. Type 'Microsoft.Translation' is not an entity type, but the type in the response payload represents an entity type. Please ensure that types defined on the client match the data model of the service, or update the service reference on the client.
```

I checked the response and found nothing wrong:

```
After the migration, gone are the good old days when Microsoft provides a handful of functions on Bing Translation. And new account keys are only valid to the new service root:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1
```

instead of something like:

```
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc
```

or:

```
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc
```

And that's not the end. When I try to add service reference to it, the VS just says:

```
EntityType 'Microsoft.Translation' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

Or throws some exception on permission.

Before that, I tried to use the Helper Class that ships with the subscription. It took me long to modify the code for use on WP8 - regarding some issues on System.Data.Services.Client (some incompatibility caused by WCF 5 on the client?) and asynchronous calls. The result was:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:There is a type mismatch between the client and the service. Type 'Microsoft.Translation' is not an entity type, but the type in the response payload represents an entity type. Please ensure that types defined on the client match the data model of the service, or update the service reference on the client.
```

I checked the response and found nothing wrong:

Microsoft Translator
  https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text='hello'&To='nl'
  
  2012-11-22T23:20:10Z
  
  
    https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text='hello'&To='nl'&$skip=0&$top=1
    Translation
    2012-11-22T23:20:10Z
    
    
      
        Hallo
      
    
  

(Sorry but the xml doesn't display properly.)

I even tried to use the traditional method for accessing OData, but all in vain. A little mad honestly...

I've googled enough but still couldn't find a solution to the new Bing Translator interface. Does anyone have similar problems with mine? Thanks in advance.

I even tried to use the traditional method for accessing OData, but all in vain. A little mad honestly...

I've googled enough but still couldn't find a solution to the new Bing Translator interface. Does anyone have similar problems with mine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use the Bing Translator for it's text-to-speech features? If so, those are built into WP8 at this point...

Comment: @JustinAngel No, I'm just trying use the text translation functionality. I doubt the issue might be associated to the VS2012 to some extent. But I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial here on how to do it in Windows Phone 7:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/wp7translate.aspx

Be sure to get your Client ID and Client Secret on Azure properly -- to do this register your app at https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications

Use the Client ID and Client Secret for the app you register here -- and not the ones for your Azure account as a whole.

Also, if you are getting errors, it's a good idea to ensure that your subscription to translator is active. You can do check this at:
https://datamarket.azure.com/account/datasets

Comment: Thanks. Actually I can get the response from the translator service manually. The problem is that .NET just cannot resolve the response properly.